# Clicking visualization properties does nothing - spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I've uploaded data (csv) into my spotfire desktop client.

The data loads in fine and I can switch visualization type.

However it won't let me change visualization properties. When I click the button nothing happens.

I've tried different datasets and rebooting spotfire and the same thing happens.

Comment: Which button are you referring to? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @rossi_182, have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling? what about right clicking on the visualization and selecting Properties? how long were you using Spotfire before this problem began? what version of the application are you using (found in Help>>About)? are you on "Spotfire Desktop" or "Spotfire Analyst"? I assume you're on Windows, so what version of Internet Explorer is currently installed?

Comment: @clesiemo3, I think rossi is referring to the gear icon in the upper right of a visualization

Comment: @niko Yes the gear icon. I am using spotfire desktop on windows. I've been using it for 6 months and this problem has creeped in within the last month.

Comment: did this start happening after an upgrade to Spotfire 7.0? there was a change to the way a lot of dialogs are rendered. make sure you meet the minimum system requirements which I believe have increased since 6.5: http://support.spotfire.com/sr_spotfire70.asp#spotfire_client. I suspect this may have to do with having an older version of Internet Explorer (9 or lower). can you please report back your IE version? and can you please let us know the answers to the other questions (version, etc in my previous comment)?

Comment: @niko Thanks for the help. I've solved it - the visualization properties pop up wasn't appearing, due to the set up of my screens. Thanks again.